# Программное взаимодействие с графическим приложением

Tags: .net, разработка-игр, gui, автоматизация

Предположим, есть какое-то полноэкранное стороннее приложение(например, какая-нибудь игра), которая использует DirectX или OpenGL.

Вопрос, а можно ли как-нибудь считать с экрана все доступные пользователю контролы(кнопки) и лейблы и взаимодействовать с ними.

Знаю, что есть .NET есть ui automation. А так же есть Spy++, который позволяет изучать интерфейс другой программы, для получения информации, которую можно использовать для автоматизации.

Справится ли они с этим? Если нет, то какой есть альтернативный подход достижения моей цели?

Важно, что бы решением можно было воспользоваться в .NET.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что есть кнопка. Если кнопку программа рисует сама, то с точки зрения системы это просто красивый рисунок, а то, что клик на эту кнопку обрабатывается программой, системе не ведомо. Если Spy++ не видит кнопку, хорошие шансы на то, что её снаружи не поймать. Исключение: WPF рисует кнопки точно так же самостоятельно, но Microsoft выставляет интерфейс для UI Automation. Так что Spy++ WPF-кнопок не увидит, но управлять ими можно.

Comment: ...а игры обычно как раз рисуют кнопки сами и сами раздают им события на основе общих данных о вводе из ОС, ничего не сообщая в ОС о том, что где находится.

Comment: Можно взаимодействовать, но скорее всего не тем способом, как это делается для десктоп приложений, работающих полностью на WinAPI, когда можно получить хэндлы и отправлять события на элементы. Для DirectX и OpenGL, если это полноценная игра, скорее всего другой подход нужен будет, .NET здесь не принципиален, важнее понимание DirectX и OpenGL.

Comment: на самый крайний случай можно юзать `sikuli`

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос довольно объемный и ответ на него зависит от многих факторов.

Наличие самописного GUI-интерфейса скорее всего лишает возможности автоматического парсинга элементов вообще.  Можно попробовать искать такие элементы с помощью поиска вызова событий (ЛКМ, ПКМ и т.д), но это имеет свои трудности.

Далее приводятся размышления на тему, связанные с полу-автоматической работой программы.

Если говорить о DirectX или OpenGL, то первое, что приходит на ум - это трассировка кода и поиск соответствующих методов вывода спрайтов, с дальнейшим их парсингом. Но это, как мне кажется, довольно долгая и нудная затея, требующая большого количества ветвений на те или иные параметры выводимого содержимого (размеры, позиция и т.д) и не факт, что оно вообще будет работать правильно.

**Для начала**, необходимо узнать, будет ли приложение находиться в фокусе постоянно или требуется возможность работы со приложением, свернутым в панель задач.

**В первом случае** можно пойти очевидным путем - "сканировать" содержимое (создание "скриншотов" скриншотером заранее написанного на языке с использованием .NET), а дальше задавать какие-либо шаблоны по размерам, форме, цвету, тексту и так далее.

Очевидно, что полу-автоматизация в самом начале лежит целиком на программисте и он должен кропотливо пройтись по всем тем или иным ситуациям, в которых появляются те или иные элементы в игре и получить с них данные (банально скриншотить элементы и сохранять их, как шаблоны).

Метод может показаться простым, но на самом деле требует массу усилий - если с кнопками будет немного проще (потому что большая часть из них квадратные, имеют три спрайта под normal, hover, click), то с лейблами , например, уже навярняка придется немного туго (прикрутить распознаватель текста, чтобы наш автоматизатор понимал, что это лейбел вообще, научить понимать конкретный шрифт конкретной игры и т.д.)

А далее - "дело техники", смотреть по шаблону и кликать/не кликать средствами самого .NET.

**Второй вариант** преследует цель работы со свернутым приложением (или нет, но это уже не суть).

В этот раз предлагается не поиск GUI-элементов непосредственно, а прямое обращение к тем или иным ячейкам памяти, как это делается в скриптах для Cheat Engine - программе все равно, какие там кнопки и как они рисуются, достаточно скормить ей нужные адреса и она будет "эмулировать" нажатия на кнопочки путем подмены значений.

Сложность данного способа заключается в том, что придется в рантайме искать эти самые элементы (тот же Cheat Engine с его memory browse, либо более тяжелая артиллерия, вроде IDA Pro + Hex Rays деббагером), а так же позаботиться о возможности восстановить адреса ячеек в случае перезапуска приложения.

Не исключен вариант, что в игру может быть встроена защита против любителей залезть в ресурсы, например, я знаю одну такую, которая на попытку просмотреть содержимое ее процесса либо вообще ничего не показывает (одни вопросы), либо выбивает ошибку.

**Не стоит забывать так же о типе игры:** одиночная или многопользовательская. Это имеет некоторое значение, так как в случае многопользовательской игры есть вариант попытать удачу в WPE PRO (либо любым другим сниффером, который умеет работать с конкретным процессом - так задача становится куда легче, чем выяснять, на какие ip-шные и с каких серверов уходят и приходят пакеты) и поймать нужные пакеты, эмулирующие те или иные действия.

Есть шанс, что Вам повезет на отсутствие токенов, публичных и секретных ключей и т.д. и т.п., обычно очень часто в этом возникают большие проблемы, так как получить приватный access-token зачастую является непосильной задачей.

Но однако удача редко улыбается в этом сигменте и зачастую игра свеч не стоит.

В любом варианте, автоматизация ожидается только после того, как Вами будет получено необходимое количество шаблонов, адресов, либо пакетов. 
**По поводу взаимодействия** с приложением - WinApi, возможно даже с хуками, либо пойти на дикое извращение - использовать другой язык (С++, например), для написании либы, которая позволяет менять значения тех или иных адресов (вплоть до ассемблерных вставок), а после осуществлять импортирование этого чуда с помощью DllImport в .NET и далее вызывать нужную функцию через него.

(Но могут существовать более простые решения).

**Более конкретная реализация.**

Например, у месть есть бот для браузерной игрушки на шарпе, все, что он делает, это просто эмулирует клик по той или иной ссылке в заданное время.

Однако, если у меня бы возникла необходимость написать бота для Desktop-игрушки, я первом делом попробовал бы найти исходные коды к боту какой-нибудь другой игры и попробовал бы изучить, как он взаимодействует с целевой игрой.

В любом случае, было бы неплохо узнать, для чего конкретно это Вам нужно, чтобы сузить круг возможных вариантов.